# How to split text into two in python?

Tags: python, function

if i'm taking input from the user something like that:

```
User_input = input("integer:")
```

and the user set 1223

my question is if there is a function that saying to the computer that the two first numbers equals to text (12 = text) and the two last equals to text_2 (23 = text_2)?

Comment: Please give some example input with its expected output.

Comment: input: "1223"; expected output: text_1= "12", text_2: "23"

Answer (score 0):

```
User_input = input("integer:")
print(User_input[:len(User_input)/2],User_input[len(User_input)/2:])
```

You will get the following output

```
integer:1234

('12', '34')
```

Comment: User_input = str(User_input)?
not int?

Comment: To convert to str else it may take as int

Comment: Your code will return `slice indices must be integers or None or have __index__ method`. Change print to: `print(User_input[:int(len(User_input)/2)],User_input[int(len(User_input)/2):])`

Comment: ```User_input=str(User_input)``` - this is not required. ```input()```  by default converts the given input to ```str```.